# Python: Inline if to print non-empty strings?

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm trying to print out just the non-empty strings in a list.  I can't seem to get the below to work, what am I doing wrong??

```
print item in mylist if item is not ""
```

Comment: What does it do?  What did you want it to do?  If you did `a = item in mylist if item is not ""` what would you expect `a` to be?  How would you add `()`'s to that statement to clarify it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following is invalid syntax: `print item in mylist if item is not ""`

You could perhaps achieve what you want using a list comprehension:

```
>>> mylist = ["foo","bar","","baz"]
>>> print [item for item in mylist if item]
['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

Comment: And, in python3, `[print(item) for item in mylist if item]` is also possible.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a generator to grab the items in the list that are not empty.

```
nonempties = (item for item in mylist if item)
```

Then loop and print or join them into a string.

```
print ' '.join(nonempties)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `filter()` built-in is well suited for exactly that, just pass `None` instead of a function:

```
>>> filter(None, ['Abc', '', 'def', None, 'ghi', False, 'jkl'])
['Abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl']
```

Details at http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html